# Is there a difference between hand soap and body soap with killing viruses?

Tags: water, solutions, ph

With the Coronavirus in full swing around the globe, I wanted an answer to this, particularly since my dad has just been diagnosed with Leukaemia.

We can't find hand wash anywhere but instead I just bought some Radox shower gel and put that in a hand soap bottle.

Is there a significant difference between hand soap and shower gel when it comes to killing off germs/viruses? Or is the case that both are detergents and it's all around marketing?

Comment: No significant difference, both will disrupt the lipid bilayer of virus particles

Comment: @Waylander are you saying the alcohol component in sanitizers is not needed? That common detergent 'soaps' will kill virus?

Comment: Alcohol based sanitisers and soaps are two different things. With a sanitiser you need an alcohol concentration of at least 60% and a long contact time. Common detergents (e.g. hand soap) do 2 things, they break up the lipid bilayer of virus particles and they facilitiate the mechanical removal of the virus from a surface (provided you rinse it off well). A soap is not a sanitiser and a sanitiser is not a soap, you use them under different circumstances.

Comment: @MarsJarsGuitars-n-Chars  Since you ask, yes soap does kill viruses  https://www.vox.com/science-and-health/2020/3/11/21173187/coronavirus-covid-19-hand-washing-sanitizer-compared-soap-is-dope

Comment: @Waylander Awesome. Thanks. Makes good sense. Wonder why this is not being stressed in news reports, etc.. The mechanical action I knew about. Strange this is not more common knowledge.

Comment: @mars wouldn't really matter, I think. .You can feel alcohol, it burns and cools as it evaporates. That feeling is what makes people relieved and sure of their cleanliness. Can't get that with soap. The feels trump the reels always...